# Spring Security: HttpSession lost after authentication

Tags: spring-security, httpsession

I'm trying to use Spring Security 3.1, but I'm losing my HttpSession after the authentication. I'm getting: "No HttpSession currently exists" after having a correct HttpSession created.

I'm getting the following log:

```
08 janv. 2014 19:53:59 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@bce8a84f: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bce8a84f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@3b40b2f: Username: ADMIN; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffff6a82: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: qx1qn1vbjxx71xedid64oi977; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN'
08 janv. 2014 19:53:59 DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'spring': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
08 janv. 2014 19:53:59 DEBUG DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
08 janv. 2014 19:53:59 DEBUG ExceptionTranslationFilter - Chain processed normally
08 janv. 2014 19:53:59 DEBUG SecurityContextPersistenceFilter - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /index at position 1 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No HttpSession currently exists
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository - No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /index at position 2 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /index at position 3 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /index at position 4 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /index at position 5 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /index at position 6 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG FilterChainProxy - /index at position 7 of 10 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
08 janv. 2014 19:54:00 DEBUG AnonymousAuthenticationFilter - Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@9055e4a6: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@957e: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
```

What could be the problem?

UPDATE:
I found my problem... I had a file that I should have cared about before:

jetty-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
    "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="sessionHandler">
        <Get name="sessionManager">
            <Set name="usingCookies" type="boolean">false</Set>
        </Get>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

I was disabling the cookies myself...

Comment: can you please update it with the xml(s), ie spring_context.xml, spring_security.xml...

Comment: @MayurGupta I solved my problem. By looking at my xml files, I found that I was disabling my cookies. Thanks

Comment: ohh yes .... you got it right, but then you should put this as an answer and you should accept it. It can be helpful for other programmers facing same issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem... I had a file that I should have cared about before:

jetty-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN"
    "http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Get name="sessionHandler">
        <Get name="sessionManager">
            <Set name="usingCookies" type="boolean">false</Set>
        </Get>
    </Get>
</Configure>
```

I was disabling the cookies myself... I've deleted this file and it's now working.